# "For loop" bash command does not execute in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, build, debian

I try to execute such a scenery via Jenkins "execute shell" build step:

```
rm -r -f _dpatch;

mkdir _dpatch;
mkdir _dpatch/deploy;

from_revision='HEAD';
to_revision='2766920';

git diff --name-only $from_revision $to_revision > "_dpatch/deploy/files.txt";

for file in $(<"_dpatch/deploy/files.txt"); do cp --parents "$file" "_dpatch"; done;

whoami
```

Build ends successfully with console output:

```
[Deploy to production] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson8315034696077699718.sh
+ rm -r -f _dpatch
+ mkdir _dpatch
+ mkdir _dpatch/deploy
+ from_revision=HEAD
+ to_revision=2766920
+ git diff --name-only HEAD 2766920
+ 
+ whoami
jenkins
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The problem is line "for file in" is just ignored, I do not understand why.

Content of files.txt is not empty and looks like this:

```
addons/tiny_mce/plugins/image/plugin.min.org.js
addons/webrtc/adapter-latest.js
templates/standard/style/review.css
```

More over, when I execute via ssh the same script in the same jenkins workspace folder under the same user (jenkins) - "for file in" line executes normally and creates files in "_dpatch" subfolder as it should.

My environment:
Debian 8,
Jenkins 2.45

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly your `/bin/sh` is a POSIX bourne shell. It think that the `$(<` construct is a bash-ism, so it will not work with `/bin/sh`.

**Try to replace**

```
$(<"_dpatch/deploy/files.txt")
```

with

```
$(cat "_dpatch/deploy/files.txt")
```

Alternatively, prepend your build step with `#!/bin/bash`.

If your login shell is `bash`, then this also explains why everything works fine via `ssh`.

Comment: Replacement "<" with "cat" fixes my problem. Thank you for fix and good explanation, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting **for** with **while** loop. And also add some more logging

```
rm -r -f _dpatch;

mkdir _dpatch;
mkdir _dpatch/deploy;

from_revision='HEAD';
to_revision='2766920';

git diff --name-only $from_revision $to_revision > "_dpatch/deploy/files.txt" && echo "git diff finished"

while IFS= read -r line; do 
    echo $line 
    cp --parent $line $_dpatch
done < _dpatch/deploy/files.txt
whoami
```

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token do `IFS= read -r line; do `

Comment: after your update and fix  "$" on " " " before "_dpatch" there are such errors on every line from files.txt: "cp: target ‘\r’ is not a directory
'\r': command not found"